# AWS HTTP error: Error creating resource: [message] fopen(): SSL operation failed with code 5

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am using AWS S3 PHP SDK.I read data from files stored on S3 using PHP. But some time in process I get below errors

```
    AWS HTTP error: Error creating resource: [message] fopen(): SSL operation failed with code 5. OpenSSL Error messages:
    error:02001018:system library:fopen:Too many open files
    error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib
    error:0B06F002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_file:system lib
    error:02001018:system library:fopen:Too many open files
    error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib
    error:0B06F002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_file:system lib
    error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

 Severity: Compile Error --> require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/project/aws/GuzzleHttp/Exception/ConnectException.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') /var/www/project/aws/aws-autoloader.php 516
```

below is the code in aws-autoloader.php that gives error

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) use ($mapping) {
    if (isset($mapping[$class])) {
        require $mapping[$class];
   }
  }, true);
```

Comment: Could you please show your code for read file?

Answer (score 0):

If your php code is getting access to s3 files over HTTPS or SFTP and does not have a way to check the validity of the SSL certificate, you will get normally this behavior.

To fix it , you must specify in your **php.ini** the path to the *.pem* file of the needed certificate. Here is the line to modify :

```
;openssl.cafile = "C: \ mycertification.pem"
```

If your're using an acm certification you may export it directly from the AWS console. You may use an IAM ROLE also to give a direct access to your php server to get it using the acm arn.

> I hope this may help you